# How to use colspan with DataTables.row.add()

Tags: datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables. Recently the client added a product line that has long model numbers. The model numbers are now too long for a single cell. I add the row like this:

```
oTable.row.add(["Quantity &amp; Model", "(1) PPJN 565.058A/4FA-J33L/42P.M", ""]);
```

This renders:

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>Quantity &amp; Model</td>
    <td>(1) PPJN 565.058A/4FA-J33L/42P.M</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to accomplish something like the following to take advantage of the last empty column:

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>Quantity &amp; Model</td>
    <td colspan="2">(1) PPJN 565.058A/4FA-J33L/42P.M</td>
    <td style="display:none;"></td>
</tr>
```

Maybe there's a way of eliminating the last column all together.

How can I make this happen? This table is not used for sorting or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the empty-cells css property.

```
table{
    empty-cells:hide;
}
```

Comment: This is do-able for the one row, but there are other rows in the table with empty cells. Do you know how to add a class/id to the row using the row.add() API? I also know that this will be the second row in the table, but I'd rather assign a class to the row - I think.

Comment: Sure - `oTable.row.add(["Quantity &amp; Model", "(1) PPJN 565.058A/4FA-J33L/42P.M", ""]).addClass('clearLastCell');` 

And of course the corresponding css: `.clearLastCell{ empty-cells:hide; }`
You'd just have to check if the last value in the array is equal to "" beforehand.